# How to read individual lines of a text from the isolated storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, isolatedstorage

(EDITED)

My codes doesn't read the text file. Apparent;y, when I want to read the file, they gave me a "File Not Found!" message box which it is in the if else loop, indicating that the code in the if loop doesn't work.

```
        private void OnSaveFile()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileName))
            {
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (store.FileExists(FileName))
                        store.DeleteFile(FileName);

                    using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                        {

                            writer.WriteLine(FileName);
                            writer.WriteLine(FileText1);
                            writer.WriteLine(FileText2);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnReadSelected()
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (store.FileExists(FileName))
                {
                    using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                        {
                            FileName = reader.ReadLine();
                            FileText1 = reader.ReadLine();
                            FileText2 = reader.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
                }
            }
        }
```

CreateTextPage:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddFileModel model = this.LayoutRoot.DataContext as AddFileModel;
            model.SaveFile.Execute(null);
            model.FileName = string.Empty;

            model.FileText1 = string.Empty;
            model.FileText2 = string.Empty;


            MessageBox.Show("File saved successfully");

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CompleteQuestionPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

ReadFilePage:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddFileModel model = this.LayoutRoot.DataContext as AddFileModel;
        model.ReadSelectedFiles.Execute(null);

    }
```

Comment: The code you've posted wouldn't even compile - `reader` will be out of scope for the second `ReadLine` call, due to not using braces on the inner `using` statement. Please post the *actual* code which is failing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sorry, I don't get what you mean. However, i am indeed getting errors for the reader. They said reader does not exist in the current context. And I was told by someone if i align reader.ReadLine(); like this, it will allow the text to be shown on diffeerent text box instead of a string of text on 1 text box.

Comment: @Jon Skeet-Thanks, I've finally know what I'm missing. Still, I can't read the file as it is still giving me the FileNot Found messagebox.

Comment: But that shows that the code you gave before *isn't* the code you had when you first got the exception. Is this now *really* the code you've got? If you step through with a debugger, presumably an exception is thrown - what *exactly* are the details of that exception?

Comment: @Jon Skeet- they said the store value is null. Btw, this set of codes are in a class file. I'm using data binding method to save and get the text.

Comment: What do you mean by "they said the store value is null" - who? Where? If that was an exception message, when I said "what exactly" I meant "cut and paste them".

Comment: @Jon Skeet-             `using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())` has a null value under the OnReadSelected.

Comment: Sorry, you're still not being very clear. You've shown a line of code - do you mean that the value of `store` is null? *After* executing that line?

Comment: @Jon Skeet- i debugged that line, is it correct?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I debugged that line"? Please try hard to be clearer - I'm having to ask for a clarification of just about everything you say.

Comment: @Jon Skeet- I'm really sorry, i dun really know much about c# programming and the features on the visual studio. I think it meant that I've been saving null values. That's why the store has nothing inside it. Is it because of the way I data bind the controls?

Comment: No, if the value of `store` is null, that has nothing to do with the value inside the file - it's before you even *get* to the file. It seems very unlikely that `GetUserStoreForApplication` would return null though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet- If you dun mind, may i post the XAML, the codes behind that calls this method, and the complete class file itself? I dunno where the problem might be.

Comment: The XAML is completely irrelevant to that line of code. If `store` really is `null`, something very odd is going on.

Comment: @Jon Skeet- it could be the way I data bind was wrong? i named my control which i want to input a text as textFileName, with the Text Binding to FileName, Mode=TwoWay. And the textblock on the different page is named titleText, with the Text Binding as FileName too, Mode=Twoway. And I've added the complete class file to the question, and the 2 codes that calls the method.

Comment: Nothing in the line of code assigning a value to `store` uses any data binding. *If* the value of `store` is null, there's something else going on. But you still haven't explained what you meant by "I debugged that line".

Comment: @Jon Skeet- I debugged the line `using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())` which is under the `public void OnReadSelected()`. Do check my edited question, i hope it might help in your assistance.

Comment: Sorry, you still haven't said what you *mean* by the phrase "I debugged the line" - you've said that value of `store` is null, do you mean *after* you've executed the line. I'm afraid I don't think I can help you, as we're clearly not communicating properly...

Comment: @Jon Skeet- i'm sorry. That error shows when i'm about to execute that line. Please tell me if this clear your doubts. I really need your help, and i'm sorry i wasn't co-operating well.

Comment: Which error? *Please* try to read your comments from the point of view of someone who can't see over your shoulder. If you mean the message box, how could that show *before* you even execute the first line of the method which is going to show it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet -mind if i post a screen shot? I really dunno how to explain it. And you are right, it is weird that the MessageBox will be executed if the codes before it should not work. So i tried to debug another line and i've got an error with that.

Comment: Sorry, I really can't keep on with this. I'm trying to get breakfast for the kids and do 101 other things at the same time (otherwise I'd have taken this to chat a long time ago). I strongly suggest you read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and rewrite your question so that it's *absolutely clear* what you're seeing... which isn't the case at the moment.

Comment: Is this the problem you were having as when you asked me? You really need to clarify the problem as it's almost impossible to understand what's going on like last time.  IIRC, you got this code from somewhere else (and you're using MVVM). I think this might be tripping you up a bit because you don't know exactly what's happening when you have someone else's code. Try recreating the problem in a new project. Read and write from the Isolated Storage and once you have that, you can move that code into your main project.

Comment: @keyboardP -true, and once again i really appreciate the helps and answers i get, even some have taught me of how wrong and how bad i was.

Comment: @lala -Helping's no problem, we all have to learn sometime :) It's just quite difficult to help when the problem isn't all that clear

Answer (score 1):

In your OnSaveFile method, it looks like you're saving the data to a file called "myfile.txt". In OnReadSelected you're opening a file using the 'Filename' property. What is 'Filename' set to? Because if it is not set to "myfile.txt", then that's probably why you're seeing 'File not found'.

Try changing

```
using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile("myfile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
```

to

```
using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(Filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
```

Also, change

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))

FileName = reader.ReadLine();
FileText1 = reader.ReadLine();
FileText2 = reader.ReadLine();
```

to

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{  
   FileName = reader.ReadLine();
   FileText1 = reader.ReadLine();
   FileText2 = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

to get your code to compile.

UPDATE:

Okay, right now in your button click handler you're doing this:

```
model.SaveFile.Execute(null);
model.FileName = string.Empty;
```

You're setting the value of 'Filename' to be an empty string; later on, you're called OnReadSelected again, which uses the value in 'Filename'. Since it's been set to an empty string, I think that's why you're seeing 'File Not Found'. What happens if you remove the line

```
model.FileName = string.Empty;
```

? Do you still get 'File Not Found'?

Comment: @E.Z.-btw, i've an error where they say reader does not exist in the context. And thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @lala - see Jon Skeet's comment above - you're missing a set of braces around the code following "using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))". That's why you're seeing 'reader does not exist'.

Comment: -I'm still getting the "File not Found!" Message Box.

Comment: How are you calling your methods? I just tried calling 'OnSaveFile' and then 'OnReadSelected' and it worked just fine.

Comment: -Would you mind if i send you the app and check for me? I swear, it is really messy. This is jsut a small portion of the codes. And I really dunnno who to turn to at this point of time.

Comment: I mean I'm serious. If you want, i can paste the whole codes here if it helps. I'm using a data binding format to get the text from the controls. The Save and Read codes are in a class file.

Comment: @lala I updated my answer - see if that change fixes your problem.

Comment: You've solved the problem @_@ I've always thought that that line of code will clear the inputted text as it is a good habit to clear off what the user has typed previously after he/she leaves the page. Thank you so much! And to the others that tried to help as well @_@

Comment: ok, that isn't the answer. The codes are just getting the words inside the textbox, and it isn't reading it from the saved file. That's why if i delete that line of code, it will just retrieve the text from the uncleared textbox after being used.

Comment: I think the original problem has changed enough that it might be a good idea to open up a new question with the current code and the current problem you're having.