# Not reading the text from the isolated storage that was saved

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, isolatedstorage

My codes doesn't read the text file. Apparent;y, when I want to read the file, they gave me a "File Not Found!" message box which it is in the if else loop, indicating that the code in the if loop doesn't work. So I need some help with this. And this question is still unanswered. By giving this much codes below, i'm just hoping that it might help you guyz understand what is my problem over here as well, because i'm not good at programming, and I'm just trying co-operate as well. Sorry to those who i've troubled a lot. Every answers you guyz gave meant something, and I really appreciate the help.

CreateTextPage XAML:

```
  <TextBox Margin="0,217,0,338" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FileName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="480" IsReadOnly="False" Name="textFileName" />
     <TextBox Text="{Binding FileText1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="447" Height="378" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="text1" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FileText2, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="447" Height="378" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="text2"/>
```

CreateTextPage:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddFileModel model = this.LayoutRoot.DataContext as AddFileModel;
            model.SaveFile.Execute(null);
            model.FileName = string.Empty;

            model.FileText1 = string.Empty;
            model.FileText2 = string.Empty;


            MessageBox.Show("File saved successfully");

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CompleteQuestionPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

ReadFilePage XAML:

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-409,-260" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="333" Text="{Binding FileName, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="titleText" />
 <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="378" Width="452"  Text="{Binding FileText1, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="textBlocky1" />
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="378" Width="452" Text="{Binding FileText2, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="textBlocky2" />
```

ReadFilePage:

```
 private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddFileModel model = this.LayoutRoot.DataContext as AddFileModel;
            model.ReadSelectedFiles.Execute(null);

        }
```

Below is the Class File in-charge of the method.

AddFileModel Class File:

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1.Model
{
    public class AddFileModel : ModelBase
    {



        private string _filename;
        public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._filename;
            }
            set
            {
                this._filename = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }

        }

        private string _filetext1;
        public string FileText1
        {
            get
            {
                return this._filetext1;
            }
            set
            {
                this._filetext1 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("FileText1");
            }

        }

        private string _filetext2;
        public string FileText2
        {
            get
            {
                return this._filetext2;
            }
            set
            {
                this._filetext2 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("FileText2");
            }
        }


        private ICommand _saveFile;
        public ICommand SaveFile
        {
            get
            {
                this._saveFile = this._saveFile ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnSaveFile);
                return this._saveFile;
            }
        }

         private ICommand _readSelectedFiles;
        public ICommand ReadSelectedFiles
        {
            get
            {
                this._readSelectedFiles = this._readSelectedFiles ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnReadSelected);
                return this._readSelectedFiles;
            }
        }

        private void OnSaveFile()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileName))
            {
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (store.FileExists(FileName))
                        store.DeleteFile(FileName);

                    using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                        {

                            writer.WriteLine(FileName);
                            writer.WriteLine(FileText1);
                            writer.WriteLine(FileText2);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnReadSelected()
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (store.FileExists(FileName))
                {
                    using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                        {
                            FileName = reader.ReadLine();
                            FileText1 = reader.ReadLine();
                            FileText2 = reader.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read individual lines of a text from the isolated storage? (EDITED)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639588/how-to-read-individual-lines-of-a-text-from-the-isolated-storage-edited)

Comment: I could not find a substantial difference between this and your previous question. You can Edit to improve and extend a question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted works fine.  Your problem must be elsewhere in your application logic.  In your read logic you don't seem to be setting the FileName property before you execute your ReadSelectedFiles command.  Your code needs this to be set because this is the file name it tries to look for. Unless you are setting this elsewhere this could be the cause of the problem.

So perhaps something like

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddFileModel model = this.LayoutRoot.DataContext as AddFileModel;
        model.FileName = "myFile.dat";
        model.ReadSelectedFiles.Execute(null);

    }
```

Comment: -what if the FileName isn't myFile.dat? It's a custom name from the FileName binding text.

Comment: You will need to find a way of setting the FileName property on your viewmodel before calling the execute on the command.  Without knowing your app I can't tell you how you should set it.